# spaCy: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: spacy

I am trying to install `spacy`  in a conda environment but the setup fails with the following error message:

```
$ pip install -U spacy --no-cache
Collecting spacy
  Downloading spacy-2.2.4.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.1 MB 4.1 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/bin/python /home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-cbh_k9yk/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.0
       cwd: None
  Complete output (41 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(_main())
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
      command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
      module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
      from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
      from .req_file import parse_requirements
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py", line 25, in <module>
      from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 28, in <module>
      from pip._internal.req.req_install import InstallRequirement
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 30, in <module>
      from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 10, in <module>
      import compileall
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
      from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
    File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 381
      raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                          ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/bin/python /home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/t2t/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-cbh_k9yk/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.0 Check the logs for full command output.
```

No idea what's happening there. `SyntaxError`?

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Very strange. Could you retry in a clean environment, and just do `pip install spacy` ?

Comment: @SofieVL I'm not at the machine right now but what I can tell so far is that it worked with `spacy==2.2.2` however, running `pip install spacy -U`, which installs `2.2.4`, will give me the error from above again.

Comment: The problem may originate from updating. To test that, you can try `pip install spacy==2.2.2` and `pip instal spacy==2.2.4`, each time in a new clean environment.

Comment: Am seeing same issue as OP running `pip install spacy -U` or `pip install spacy==2.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I described what worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061184/spacy-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1).  I was getting similar errors trying to install spaCy into a 32-bit environments.  When I rebuilt my virtualenv as 64-bit, I was able to install just fine.